# Ubicar ciudad de google maps con un select

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, json, google-maps

Buenas tengo un maps en una vista de laravel y arriba tengo un select con un foreach que me devuelve las ciuidades de colombia, como puedo hacer para cuando le de click a una ciudad google maps se redireccione a esa ciudad automaticamente

esta es mi vista, quiero que al seleccionar la ciudad google maps redireccione a esa ciudad

[image: vista de maps]

y este es el foreach que recorre las ciudades y el map

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya tienes guardada las posiciones [x,y] de las ciudades?

Answer (score 3):

Si lo que quieres es abrir google maps en otra pestaña solo tienes que construir la URL

```
https://www.google.com/maps/place/  + Nombre de la ciudad
```

por ejemplo ciudad de San Luis Potosi, Capital

```
https://www.google.com/maps/place/San+Luis,+S.L.P.
```

Y en automático te enviará a google maps visualizando esa ciudad.

Si lo que tienes es un mapa de google dentro de tu sitio utilizando la API, un buen ejemplo es el de geocoding
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

```
<div id="floating-panel">
      <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Sydney, NSW">
      <input id="submit" type="button" value="Geocode">
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}
        });
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
          geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
        });
      }

      function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
        var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
        geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: resultsMap,
              position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
          } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

Comment: ya lo tengo en mi app y me salen las cordenadas que yo apunte en unos label, pero tengo un select arriba donde puedo seleccionar las ciudades de colombia, y yo necesito que al seleccionar BOGOTA, el maps redireccione a bogota cabe recarcar que es una vista de laravel

Comment: La idea es absolutamente la misma, no importa si es un campo de texto o un select, en el ejemplo que te deje usan el evento sumit de un formulario, reemplaza eso y por el evento change de tu select